# How do I create a figure of these two separate polar plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to create two separate plots as subplots, on the same figure. Both plots are polar. My attempts cause them to plot on the same graph.

```
def GenerateTrigonometryTable(x): #Define Function
    A = np.arange (0,360,x) 
    B = np.sin(A*np.pi/180)  
    C = np.cos(A*np.pi/180)
    table = np.dstack(([A],[B],[C])) 
    return table 
Theta = (GenerateTrigonometryTable(5)[:,:,0]) 
STheta = (GenerateTrigonometryTable(5)[:,:,1])
CTheta = (GenerateTrigonometryTable(5)[:,:,2])

ax1 = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax1.plot(Theta.flatten(), STheta.flatten())
ax2 = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax2.plot(Theta.flatten(), CTheta.flatten())

fig.show()
```

This plots it on the same graph and I need it to be a figure of two separate graphs.

Comment: this is python matplotlib not matlab; should adjust your tags.

Comment: Your python is ill indented - `IndentationError` as is.

Comment: why do you use the same `111` for both subplots?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following: `121` means first plot on a 1x2 subplots grid and `122` means second plot on that 1x2 subplots grid.

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, projection='polar')
ax1.plot(Theta.flatten(), STheta.flatten())
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, projection='polar')
ax2.plot(Theta.flatten(), CTheta.flatten())

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A more object-oriented approach would be :

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='polar')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='polar')
ax1.plot(Theta.flatten(), STheta.flatten())
ax2.plot(Theta.flatten(), CTheta.flatten())

fig.show()
```

Equivalent of Sheldore's answer but shows how figures, axes and plots are articulated in matplotlib.